# Jquery ajax() call fails in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following code for submitting data using ajax from forms of class `ajax`. this works perfectly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome but fails in IE.

```
ajax: function() {
      $('form.ajax').live('submit', function() {
        var form_ajax = $(this);

        $.ajax({
          url: form_ajax.attr('action'),
          data: form_ajax.serialize(),
          type: form_ajax.attr('method'),
          dataType: 'script',
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {

            $('#ajax-bid-new .ajax-form-error, #ajax-bid-new .ajax-form-success').remove();
            form_ajax.slideUp();

          }
        });

        return false;
      });
```

Please help - I am stuck here for past 2 days. I am returning a Javascript file from server to be evaluated inside browser. This works as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but **IE receives it as a file and opens up the file download dialog**.

What can I do in IE to make this work? I tried by dropping the following code in my `application.js` file (I'm doing a rails project btw)

```
// public/javascripts/application.js
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})
```

I get the same behavior from IE even after writing the `ajaxSetup` block like above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `live` [doesn't work with `submit`](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie-specific-issues-with-live-submit) in IE. Have you tried using a normal submit instead:

```
$('form.ajax').submit(function() {
```

Comment: submit does not work.. I am new to javascript and javascript and i ugess the request is sent asynchronously correctly with my above code - only when IE recieves a js - instead of evaluating the js, it is rendering it

Answer (score 0):

**To catch live form submit events in IE, instead of:**

```
$("form").live("submit", function() { ... });
```

to

```
var submitHandler = function() { ... };
$("body").children().each(function() {
      $("form", this).live("submit", submitHandler);
})
```

**Point to be noted**

- IE caches AJAX requests really aggressively (more so than Firefox, anyway). You need to set the Cache-Control headers in the response appropriately if this is not right for your site.
- change your content type, last time i fixed similar problem by changing content-type from application/json; charset=utf8 to just plain application/json
- [jQueries' bind and live behaviours along with the liveQuery plugin](http://www.slideshare.net/rapaul/jquery-behaviours)

Answer (score 0):

LiveQuery plugin solved the problem  http://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery